# Android manage app if Not Responsing from server

Tags: android, android-networking

im my Application i'm using networking and my problem is if fetch from server not Responsing or delay is long my app alert me to App Not Responsing, are you sure to Force close or waiting. i want to manage that to 10 second if if fetch from server not Responsing alert to user wait and disable Android `force close` & `wait`. Thanks

My simple code to connect server for fetch data is :

```
public void getReceivedSMS(long start, long count) {

    /* Connect to Server*/
    tsms = new TSMS(context, new User(this.username, this.password));

    try {

        /* Fetch From connected Server */
        rows = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);

        saveRowsintoDatabase(rows);

    } catch (TException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

ProcessTask:

```
class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String > {
    SoapObject req1;
    private String result;
    public ProcessTask(SoapObject rq) {
        req1 = rq;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(this.req1);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        try {
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + this.req1.getName(), envelope);
            this.result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE))) {
            try {
                throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        return this.result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check depending on what your tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count); returns is it a Json Array or something simillar then you will check on that variable, also it is recommended to run your HTTP request from an AsyncTask separated from your UI